# How do you Horizontally center align a DIV that is absolutely positioned in another DIV?

Tags: css

How do you Horizontally center align a DIV that is absolutely positioned in another DIV ?

HTML

```
<div style="width:250px;height:250px;background:red;position:relative;">
    <div style="width:100px;height:100px;background:blue;position:absolute;"></div>
</div>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer works only if the background of the inner `div` has no background color. As your example does, I add a third `div`. The second one is for the centering, the third one is for the coloring.

```
<div style="width:250px;height:250px;background:red;position:relative;">
  <div style="width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;padding-left:50%;margin-left:-50px">
    <div style="background:blue;padding:0px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The important thing to notice here is: `padding-left:50%;margin-left:-50px;`. `-50px` being half of you div's width.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:250px;height:250px;background:red;position:relative;">
    <div style="width:100px;height:100px;background:blue;position:absolute; margin: auto;"></div>
</div>
```

the margin auto should center your div both horizontally and vertically

Comment: Yes and no... depends of the browser.

Comment: Yep, it depends... problems were on ie6 and opera, if i'm not wrong... maybe ie7 too. If you need full cross-browsing, then 'margin-left:75px' and 'margin-right:75px' is the answer, but it's bounded to your external_div_width - internal_div_width

Answer (score 0):

If you know the sizes of each `div` and you plan to continue to use `position:absolute;`, you just set the `top` and `left` coordinates.  So something like this in the inner `div`

`top:75px; left:75px;`

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/zQjaU/

*May be off a few px.  You may need to adjust.